# ¿Cómo se hace un gráfico de dos líneas (variables)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Este es mi código y me sale el gráfico en blanco:

```
combinado_def_cont %>%
ggplot(aes(x=cat)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = contagios), color = "darkred") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = defunciones), color="steelblue", linetype="twodash")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="plain", color= NULL, 
                           size=10, angle=90),
          axis.text.y = element_text(face="plain", color= NULL, 
                           size=8, angle=90))
```

[image: Estos son los datos!]

---

Muchas gracias amigos
Voy a tratar de copiar los datos en columnas

cat Contagios Defunciones 
[0,5)   972 2 
[5,10)  1524    3 
[10,15) 2648    2 
[15,20) 7585    1 
[20,25) 17911   20 
[25,30) 23413   18 
[30,35) 22380   39 
[35,40) 19647   73 
[40,45) 14253   95 
[45,50) 10906   123 
[50,55) 10174   195 
[55,60) 8868    279 
[60,65) 6942    400 
[65,70) 4870    449 
[70,75) 3262    426 
[75,80) 2225    412 
[80,85) 1431    306 
[85,90) 705 224 
[90,95) 298 100 
[95,100) 78 27 
[100,105] 9 4

Comment: Hola Derlis Salinas. Tu pregunta, si bien breve, es clara y está bien formulada. Podrías mejorarla agregando los datos en un formato que se puede copiar y pegar, en lugar de una captura de pantalla. La función `dput(combinado_def_cont)` genera el código con el se pueden reproducir tus datos en cualquier sesión de `R`. Si bien la imagen ayuda a entender el problema hace muy dificultoso reproducir exactamente el error.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que usando `geom_line` es necesario definir el grupo al que pertenecen las observaciones, así la función sabe como conectar las líneas. Eso lo haces con el argumento `group =`. En el caso que presentas se resuelve bastante fácil con `group = 1` en el `aes` de `geom_line`.

```
library(tidyverse)
#Creo unos datos con una estructura similar a la de los tuyos. 
tibble(
  cat = letters, 
  contagios = rpois(26, 700), 
  defunciones = rpois(26, 150 )
) -> combinado_def_cont

combinado_def_cont %>%
ggplot(aes(x=cat)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = contagios, group = 1), #Aquí está el cambio: group = 1
                color = "darkred") +
  geom_line(aes(y = defunciones, group = 1), #Lo mismo acá
                color="steelblue", linetype="twodash")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="plain", color= NULL, 
                                   size=10, angle=90),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="plain", color= NULL, 
                                   size=8, angle=90))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente no se ve igual porque los datos son aleatorios de una distribución Poisson, pero debería funcionar.
Alternativamente puedes pasar tus datos a formato de pares de variables valores y graficar las dos líneas en un solo paso. En tu caso que tienes solo dos variables quizás no valga la pena, pero si son muchísimas líneas esta opción simplifica las cosas:

```
combinado_def_cont %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contagios:defunciones, 
               names_to = "variable", 
               values_to = "valor") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cat, 
             y = valor, 
             color = variable, 
             group = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
combinado_def_cont %>%
ggplot(aes(x=cat)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = contagios, group = 1), color = "darkred") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = defunciones, group = 1), color="steelblue", linetype="twodash")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="plain", color= "#E69F00", 
                           size=10, angle=90),
          axis.text.y = element_text(face="plain", color= "#000099", 
                           size=8, angle=90))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcionó muy bien lo de group. Ahora me falta poner en dos ejes los datos para que sea legible.